# why not the regexp match different from the file and the variable?

Tags: regex, string, go

when i do a regexp match using golang. what's the different between the file and the variable?
1. in var

```
str:=`<Row ss:Height="19.8">
 <Cell ss:StyleID="s74"><Data>{{range $prj:=.prj}}</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" >
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s71"><Data>{{$prj.PrjName}}</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s72"><Data>{{$prj.ReplyNo}}</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
   <Cell><Data>{{end}}</Data></Cell>
   </Row>`
   re := regexp.MustCompile(`<Row[^>]*>[\s\S.].*({{[range|end].*?}})</Data></Cell>[\s\S]*?</Row>`)
   fmt.Println(re.MatchString(str)) //it is true!
```

2. from the file.

   body, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./ag.xml")  //ap.xml content is the str's contents
   str := string(body) //str is the above 1 str's contents
   re := regexp.MustCompile(`<Row[^>]*>[\s\S.].*({{[range|end].*?}})</Data></Cell>[\s\S]*?</Row>`)
   fmt.Println(re.MatchString(str)) //but the result alaways is false?

What's the different in them? how to  solve it?

Comment: body==str is true? If not, you are not reading the same content.

Comment: ioutil.ReadFile is no error.

Comment: why not try to save the str into a file, and then read from the file ,and then do a match?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a try like this...

```
body, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./ag.xml") //ap.xml content is the str's contents
str := string(body) //str is the above 1 str's contents
re := regexp.MustCompile(< R o w [^>]*> [\s\S.].*({{[range|end].*?}}) < / D a t a > < / C e l l > [\s\S]*? < / R o w >)
fmt.Println(re.MatchString(str))
```

I might have missed spaces inbetween characters, check it once again. If this works out that it means that the file which you are using is UTF16 charset or something but your regexp is matching with the string, so you might need to convert UTF16 to string and match it.